# Bootstrap Tooltips not working (though it appears on the DOM)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to use bootstrap's tooltip feature on a dynamically created set of divs, and when i hover i can see in chrome's inspector that the div itself is modified as it is supposed to (title value is passed to data-original-title) AND that the generated tooltip's div itself is appended as expected (either next to my div or in the body if i set it to), but nothing appears.
After looking for a while i found a jsfiddle explaining a solution for another tooltip-related problem, but i found out it had exactly the same problem.
I simplified it so you can see for yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/uDF4N/95/

```
<a id="hop" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Apps">coucou</a>
```

As you can see, on hover the tooltip appears in the DOM, but is not displayed.
I tried with IE11 as well.

Any idea on what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Someone already posted comment then deleted it. I was just going to upvote. To fix this issue just remove your extra bootstrap.min.js includes and it works. You are including Bootstrap i think 2 times in this jsfiddle

Comment: @NickTimmer That was me, I thought better about posting a large block of code as a comment so I removed it and was going to post an answer instead. I think you are the right man for the job though :)

Comment: no. you post your answer :)  @MasterYoda

Comment: Right, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You're including `bootstrap.min.js` twice. just remove one.
    http://jsfiddle.net/uDF4N/97/

Copied from @MasterYoda's comment

Comment: Actually it works on the jsfiddle but that didn't solve the issue on my site :
if i remove the bootstrap include line, when i call the tooltip() function it says : `Uncaught TypeError: point.tooltip is not a function`

and the bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) says "You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js"

Comment: I switched to the jquery-ui tooltip feature, works ok.